# Testing Mobile App with Appium & WebdriverIO: "No route found for /session"

Tags: android, react-native, automated-tests, appium, webdriver-io

I want to set up the process of **automated testing** of mobile applications for Android and iOS platforms (React Native) . For this I use [Appium](http://appium.io/) and [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io/docs/gettingstarted). As an example, I am using existing [appium-boilerplate](https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate/) codebase and a ready-made [application](https://github.com/webdriverio/native-demo-app/releases) for running tests. I run the application in the **Android emulator**. Basic settings are presented below.

**1. Appium**

[image]

[image]

**2. WebdriverIO**

*wdio.shared.conf.js*

```
exports.config = {
    // ====================
    // Runner and framework
    // Configuration
    // ====================
    runner: 'local',
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        // Updated the timeout to 30 seconds due to possible longer appium calls
        // When using XPATH
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 90000,
        helpers: [require.resolve('@babel/register')],
    },
    sync: true,
    logLevel: 'silent',
    deprecationWarnings: true,
    bail: 0,
    baseUrl: 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com',
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 90000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    reporters: ['spec'],

    // ====================
    // Appium Configuration
    // ====================
    services: [
        [
            'appium',
            {
            // For options see
            // https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/packages/wdio-appium-service
                args: {
                    // Auto download ChromeDriver
                    relaxedSecurity: true,
                    // chromedriverAutodownload: true,
                    // For more arguments see
                    // https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/tree/master/packages/wdio-appium-service
                },
                command: 'appium',
            },
        ],
    ],
    port: 4723,
};
```

*wdio.android.app.conf.js*.

```
const { join } = require('path');
const { config } = require('./wdio.shared.conf');

// ============
// Specs
// ============
config.specs = [
    './tests/specs/**/app*.spec.js',
];

// ============
// Capabilities
// ============
// For all capabilities please check
// http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#general-capabilities
config.capabilities = [
    {
        // The defaults you need to have in your config
        platformName: 'Android',
        maxInstances: 1,
        // For W3C the appium capabilities need to have an extension prefix
        // http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/
        // This is `appium:` for all Appium Capabilities which can be found here
        'appium:udid': 'emulator-5554',
        'appium:deviceName': 'Android SDK build for x86_64',
        'appium:platformVersion': '10.0',
        'appium:orientation': 'PORTRAIT',
        // `automationName` will be mandatory, see
        // https://github.com/appium/appium/releases/tag/v1.13.0
        'appium:automationName': 'Appium',
        // The path to the app
        'appium:app': join(process.cwd(), './apps/Android-NativeDemoApp-0.2.1.apk'),
        // Read the reset strategies very well, they differ per platform, see
        // http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/
        'appium:noReset': true,
        'appium:newCommandTimeout': 240,
    },
];

exports.config = config;
```

**3. Steps**

First I open Android emulator and start the Appium server:

[image]

[image]

Then I use the command to run the tests `npm run android.app`. After that, the test cases are executed in the background, but **nothing happens in the emulator** and in the terminal I see the message `[HTTP] No route found for /session`

[image]

**My question is:** what do need to pay attention to in order to fix this? Because I don't know what to look at and how to set up the configuration correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you should try to set the path variable in config?

Answer (score 32):

I got rid of the problem by using this command to start Appium server in the terminal:

```
appium --base-path /wd/hub
```

And use this setting in the Appium inspector

[image: And use this setting in the Appium inspector]

By the way, it might still not work if you use iOS simulator/device with version >= 15 with Appium 1.21 because that doesn't support iOS 15. You have to install an older iOS simulator to solve it.

Comment: This is mentioned in the Appium Inspector github project readme as well (see: https://github.com/appium/appium-inspector#important-migration-notes).

"[..] If you're using Appium Inspector with an Appium 1.x server, you'll likely need to update the path information in the New Session form back to `/wd/hub`.[..]"

Answer (score 14):

We were able to resolve this issue by overriding the `path` variable in the wdio.conf.js:

```
...
path: '/wd/hub',
port: 4723,
services: ['appium'],
...
```

Without the path defined it apparently defaults to `/session` which fails with a 404 as you saw.

Comment: If coming from https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate or similar setups you can avoid this issue by not starting your own server as stated below in Matheus's answer.

Comment: @nicholascm that's a fair point. That being said, this is necessary (afaik) if you want to have it connect to a pre-running appium server.

Answer (score 4):

**Do not run appium server alone.**

use directly the webdriver command to run the tests.

Example for android: `npm run android.app`

Comment: For a lot of people this is probably the issue. Going from the appium-boilerplate, you can hack it to work above by modifying the path and starting your own appium server as stated in the accepted answer, however, it "just works" if you let the command above start the server.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I did fixed it.
I don't know why, but it works with locally install Appium npm package.