# WebdriverIO not using config.path to access Appium Server

Tags: appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

I'm trying to get started with appium and successfully connected myself with my device using Appium Server and Appium Inspector (I had to change remote path to /wd/hub). Now, I'm trying to do the same using WebdriverIO using https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate

At first I start the appium server:

[image]

Now I cloned Appium Boilerplate from https://github.com/webdriverio/appium-boilerplate and ran `npm install`. Then I changed the path in `config/wdio.android.app.conf.ts` to '/wd/hub':

```js
import { join } from 'path';
import config from './wdio.shared.local.appium.conf';

// ============
// Specs
// ============
config.specs = [
    './tests/specs/**/app*.spec.ts',
];

// ============
// Capabilities
// ============
// For all capabilities please check
// http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#general-capabilities
config.capabilities = [
    {
        // The defaults you need to have in your config
        platformName: 'Android',
        maxInstances: 1,
        // For W3C the appium capabilities need to have an extension prefix
        // http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/
        // This is `appium:` for all Appium Capabilities which can be found here
        'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel_3_10.0',
        'appium:platformVersion': '10.0',
        'appium:orientation': 'PORTRAIT',
        'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
        // The path to the app
        'appium:app': join(process.cwd(), './apps/Android-NativeDemoApp-0.4.0.apk'),
        // @ts-ignore
        'appium:appWaitActivity': 'com.wdiodemoapp.MainActivity',
        // Read the reset strategies very well, they differ per platform, see
        // http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/other/reset-strategies/
        'appium:noReset': true,
        'appium:newCommandTimeout': 240,
    },
];

config.path = '/wd/hub';
console.log(config);
exports.config = config;
```

Now I call `npm run android.app`, and the console.log command shows me:

```
{
  runner: 'local',
  specs: [ './tests/specs/**/app*.spec.ts' ],
  capabilities: [
    {
      platformName: 'Android',
      maxInstances: 1,
      'appium:deviceName': 'Pixel_3_10.0',
      'appium:platformVersion': '10.0',
      'appium:orientation': 'PORTRAIT',
      'appium:automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
      'appium:app': '<<removed initially ;-)>>',
      'appium:appWaitActivity': 'com.wdiodemoapp.MainActivity',
      'appium:noReset': true,
      'appium:newCommandTimeout': 240
    }
  ],
  logLevel: 'silent',
  bail: 0,
  baseUrl: 'http://the-internet.herokuapp.com',
  waitforTimeout: 45000,
  connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
  connectionRetryCount: 3,
  services: [ [ 'appium', [Object] ] ],
  framework: 'mocha',
  reporters: [ 'spec' ],
  mochaOpts: { ui: 'bdd', timeout: 180000 },
  port: 4723,
  path: '/wd/hub'
}
```

... which seems ok for me, but the Appium server shows:

```
[HTTP] Waiting until the server is closed
[HTTP] Received server close event
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.22.0
[Appium] Non-default server args:
[Appium]   address: 127.0.0.1
[Appium]   sessionOverride: true
[Appium]   relaxedSecurityEnabled: true
[Appium]   allowInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium]   denyInsecure: {
[Appium]   }
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
[HTTP] --> POST /session
[HTTP] {"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"platformName":"Android","appium:deviceName":"Pixel_3_10.0","appium:platformVersion":"10.0","appium:orientation":"PORTRAIT","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:app":"<<removed ;-)>>","appium:appWaitActivity":"com.wdiodemoapp.MainActivity","appium:noReset":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":240},"firstMatch":[{}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"Android","appium:deviceName":"Pixel_3_10.0","appium:platformVersion":"10.0","appium:orientation":"PORTRAIT","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:app":"<<removed ;-)>>","appium:appWaitActivity":"com.wdiodemoapp.MainActivity","appium:noReset":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":240}}
[HTTP] No route found for /session
[HTTP] <-- POST /session 404 8 ms - 211
[HTTP] 
[HTTP] --> POST /session
[HTTP] {"capabilities":{"alwaysMatch":{"platformName":"Android","appium:deviceName":"Pixel_3_10.0","appium:platformVersion":"10.0","appium:orientation":"PORTRAIT","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:app":"<<removed ;-)>>","appium:appWaitActivity":"com.wdiodemoapp.MainActivity","appium:noReset":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":240},"firstMatch":[{}]},"desiredCapabilities":{"platformName":"Android","appium:deviceName":"Pixel_3_10.0","appium:platformVersion":"10.0","appium:orientation":"PORTRAIT","appium:automationName":"UiAutomator2","appium:app":"<<removed ;-)>>","appium:appWaitActivity":"com.wdiodemoapp.MainActivity","appium:noReset":true,"appium:newCommandTimeout":240}}
```

It looks like WebdriverIO doesn't recognize the config.path-setting. I was already checking out [Testing Mobile App with Appium & WebdriverIO: "No route found for /session"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67458824/testing-mobile-app-with-appium-webdriverio-no-route-found-for-session) but the solution was changing the config.path value (which I did) but I've no idea why it's no recognized... Is anyone having any idea?

Answer (score 4):

i just stepped over the same issue and it looks like it works when you set it under the **capabilites**:

```
 capabilities: [{
    "path": "/wd/hub",
    ...
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you solved an issue I was getting mad with :)

Comment: Thanks - pointing in the right direct.