# HOOK-ERROR in before_scenario: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'

Tags: python, cucumber, appium, python-behave

I'm trying to write this test framework using Behave and Appium.

I've got this fixture file with a setup_android_driver that keeps returning the error

```
@fixture
def setup_android_driver(context):
    print('this is a fixture for android driver')
    context.android_driver = initialize_android_driver()
    yield context.android_driver
    context.android_driver.quit()
```

My initialize_android_driver is referenced in my appium_driver.py file like this:

```
def initialize_android_driver():
    print(desired_caps_android)
    return webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps_android)
```

And my desired_caps_android is defined correctly within the config file for a real device I have because i'm testing the value to print out correctly during the initialization.

And my before_scenario is in my environment.py file looks like this:

```
def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    print('this is before scenario')
    if 'iOS' in scenario.tags:  # You can use tags to identify iOS scenarios
        context.ios_driver = setup_ios_driver
    else:
        context.android_driver = setup_android_driver  # Make sure this step is performed
        # Register the setup_android_driver fixture
        use_fixture(setup_android_driver, context)
        # Now you can access the Android driver in your step definitions using 'context.android_driver'.
```

I'm thinking somewhere my desired capabilities are getting translated as a None type, but I can't figure out where.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by using load_capabilities in UiAutomator2Options and passing in my caps there. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77118636/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-to-capabilities-getting-th).

```
    def initialize_android_driver():
    appium_server_url = 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub'

    # Converts capabilities to AppiumOptions instance
    capabilities_options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(desired_caps_android)

    return webdriver.Remote(command_executor=appium_server_url, options=capabilities_options)
```

but then when i went to start my appium server I kept getting another error

```
 [debug] [HTTP] No route found for //session
```

which I resolved by starting the appium server with base path defined, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67458824/testing-mobile-app-with-appium-webdriverio-no-route-found-for-session).

```
 appium --base-path /wd/hub
```